# How to observe a flutter application is closed if we close the application trough task manager?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am working on a basic timer application in flutter. After the user start the countdown and minimize the application I want to show an ongoing notification with the timer in notification panel(which I am able to achieve), but if the user close the application through the task manager the ongoing notification don't get destroyed and although the countdown not working(in the notification body) but the notification still exist and don't get destroyed.

I am using WidgetsBindingObserver to check the application lifecycle and show or close the notification

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('is paused');
        locator.get<NotificationService>().showCountDownNotification();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('is resumed');
        locator.get<NotificationService>().closeCountDownNotification();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('is inactive');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print('is detached');
        // If notification countdown running than close it...
        // locator.get<NotificationService>().closeCountDownNotification();
        await locator
            .get<NotificationService>()
            .flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
            .cancelAll();
        break;
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
```

But the problem is that the detached is not called when we close the application through task manager, I tried to put the closeCountDown method in the `dispose()` method of my root widget widget, but it seems disposed also don't gets called when closing the application through task manager.

How can I achieve something like if there is an ongoing notification and we close the application through the task manager than the ongoing notification will also gets destroyed?

Comment: Setting a timeout to close the notification after certain period of time seems to work in my case...but I still want to know if it's possible to know and run some function when the application is closed through the task manager.